# Установка отступа для абзаца с помощью :before

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток
Почему это не работает? Ведь должно же

```css
p:before {
  content: "  ";
}
```

```html
<p>Кто может оспорить ошеломляющую популярность этой книги во всем мире. И не случайно именно  "Властелин Колец" стал своего рода каноном, положившим начало новому жанру в мире литературы, - фэнтези.</p>
<p>Удивительный, сказочный, полный опасностей и приключений, находящийся под вечным противостоянием добра и зла, этот мир в то же время так похож на наш, что никто не остается равнодушным к Средиземью и героям, его населяющим.</p>
<p>На долю маленького, добродушного хоббита Фродо выпала участь пройти через все Средиземье в Темные земли Мордора и уничтожить Кольцо Всевластья, которое обладает чудовищной, разрушительной силой. </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

```css
p:before {
  content: "\00a0  ";  
}
```

```html
<p>Кто может оспорить ошеломляющую популярность этой книги во всем мире. И не случайно именно  "Властелин Колец" стал своего рода каноном, положившим начало новому жанру в мире литературы, - фэнтези.</p>
<p>Удивительный, сказочный, полный опасностей и приключений, находящийся под вечным противостоянием добра и зла, этот мир в то же время так похож на наш, что никто не остается равнодушным к Средиземью и героям, его населяющим.</p>
<p>На долю маленького, добродушного хоббита Фродо выпала участь пройти через все Средиземье в Темные земли Мордора и уничтожить Кольцо Всевластья, которое обладает чудовищной, разрушительной силой. </p>
```

**Вариант 2**

```css
p:before {
  content: "";
  width: 15px; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Кто может оспорить ошеломляющую популярность этой книги во всем мире. И не случайно именно  "Властелин Колец" стал своего рода каноном, положившим начало новому жанру в мире литературы, - фэнтези.</p>
<p>Удивительный, сказочный, полный опасностей и приключений, находящийся под вечным противостоянием добра и зла, этот мир в то же время так похож на наш, что никто не остается равнодушным к Средиземью и героям, его населяющим.</p>
<p>На долю маленького, добродушного хоббита Фродо выпала участь пройти через все Средиземье в Темные земли Мордора и уничтожить Кольцо Всевластья, которое обладает чудовищной, разрушительной силой. </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте с помощью `text-ident`:

```css
p {
   text-indent: 20px; /* Отступ первой строки в пикселах */
}
```

```html
<p>Кто может оспорить ошеломляющую популярность этой книги во всем мире. И не случайно именно  "Властелин Колец" стал своего рода каноном, положившим начало новому жанру в мире литературы, - фэнтези.</p>
<p>Удивительный, сказочный, полный опасностей и приключений, находящийся под вечным противостоянием добра и зла, этот мир в то же время так похож на наш, что никто не остается равнодушным к Средиземью и героям, его населяющим.</p>
<p>На долю маленького, добродушного хоббита Фродо выпала участь пройти через все Средиземье в Темные земли Мордора и уничтожить Кольцо Всевластья, которое обладает чудовищной, разрушительной силой. </p>
```